# Inserting auto-incremented value in another table row

Tags: php, mysql

I've been scouring the internet for over an hour now searching for the solution to this problem I'm having, and I've probably found it but I'm still confused:

I have this MySQL table that contains information about my band's gigs, including but not limited to: the date, start time, an event description, etc., and then a column called `venue_id`, which is a foreign key related to a table which contains information about venues we've played at (venue name, address, website, etc.).

The way I've set up the form we'll use to create new gigs in the Gigs table is, for the venue info, there is a drop-down select menu which gets populated with options selected from the Venues table:

```
<?php
function venueSelectPopper($conn) {
    $queryVenueNames = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT ID, venue_name FROM venues_played_at ORDER BY venue_name;');

    while($DB_venueName = mysqli_fetch_array($queryVenueNames)) {
        $DOC_venueName .=  '<option value="' . $DB_venueName[ID] . '">' . $DB_venueName[venue_name] . '</option>\n';
    }
    return $DOC_venueName;
}
?>

// HTML

<select name='venues-played-at' id='pick-venue'>
    <option value="">Select Venue</option>
    <?php echo venueSelectPopper($conn);?>
</select>
```

Works fine, no problems here, however, if we're playing at a new venue then we'll obviously have create that new row in the Venues table first in order for the `venue_id` column in the Gigs table to have any reference.

**So how would I go about creating AND retrieving that value all in one go when submitting to Gigs table?**

As I said, I've been looking for a solution for some time and I'm gathering that AJAX might come to my rescue here, but the only answers that come up are either in jQuery, which I'm avoiding learning for the time being as I'm still working on learning the fundamentals; or they're referring to other languages like Java or C+ that I'm not even close to learning yet.

Comment: check out [`mysqli_stmt_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php) to get the `venue_id` to insert into the gigs table.

Comment: By the way, Wrap you array keys with quotes, $DB_venueName['ID'] instead of $DB_venueName[ID] and initialise $DOC_venueName with an empty value before while() loop.